# Does a e-commerce website site really need an 'introduction' on the homepage?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce, homepage

It's common on websites to have text on the homepage to introduce the company. I'm wondering if, for most websites, especially e-commerce websites that isn't actually necessary, especially when the UI is self explanatory.

Is there an overall benefit to providing an introduction on the homepage?

Comment: Do you mean for *all possible websites out there*? That seems like quite a sweeping generalisation.

Comment: I rephrased my question slightly to make it less general...

Comment: I've removed the request for pro's and con's as that doesn't really fit with a Q&A site, we need a question that has an actual answer.

Comment: Fair enough JonW.

Answer (score 1):

A homepage intro can go a long ways, even if it's just a two sentence blurb. It doesn't need to be three paragraphs, or even one, explaining the entire history of the company, but a little something to ensure the user that this site is what it looks like will help.

Most likely the user will understand instantly that they're on an ecommerce site. Then the question becomes, what is this site specializing in? Is it the stuff I just searched on google? Or is their focus in something not well related, and they just happen to have a page with products similar to what I'm looking for.

I've personally found myself in the above situation, where I'm browsing around for something, and via organic search, I come across an ecommerce site with some similar things, but I have no idea what the site is specializing in because it doesn't have a clear theme. In these cases, I might see the stuff I'm looking for, but I'm still left a little uneased because I've never seen this site before, and it's not clear they exist to sell X related product, rather, they just happen to have a page with it amongst other products with no apparent theme.

Basically, if you're an ecommerce site, and you're not amazon, or the online shop of a major department store, you probably have a specific theme. Example: Hair care products, lawn care and power tools, etc. Make that clear. Users are much more at ease when they completely understand where they are, especially when they're about to pull out their credit card, and they're much more likely to stay on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on what your website is providing.
If the website is a local business or service, then definitely needs explanation.

If the website is an online service or product, it probably still needs explanation.

That is, unless you're an e-commerce site as big as Amazon and everybody knows who you are anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A company / person introduction on a home page or for any other can go towards supporting the authenticity of the site and it's content.

The introduction if written well contains all the structured data that search engines used to link information and data together.

Take a look at [www.schema.org](http://www.schema.org) and [google structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) as these demonstrate the techniques and benefits required to make the most out of the content included on pages.

Many common content items seen on many sites have reasons for being that are far more relevant in supporting the reason the site or service exists in the first place rather than solely supporting a user experience. Referring back to authenticity most informational descriptive texts go a long way to help create a level of trust created from clarity and contact-ability.